# If statements questions in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write the following code in OCaml:

```
let a = 0
let b = 1 

if a > b then 
  {
    print_endline "a";
    print_endline "a";
  }
print_endline "b"
```

And then I encountered the following error:

```
File "[21]", line 4, characters 0-2:
4 | if a > b then 
    ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

I have tried using the `begin` and `end` keywords.

Comment: Very little of this bears any resemblance to OCaml. OCaml does not use curly brackets for scoping, semicolon is not a statement terminator and local variable bindings have the form `let <pattern> = <expression> in <expression>`. Perhaps you should try following [a tutorial](http://ocamlverse.net/content/learning.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing a program (rather than mucking about in a REPL), then there are only certain constructs which can exist at the top level of your program.

One of those is a binding. So the following is fine:

```
let a = 0
let b = 1
```

But a conditional expression (if/else) is not permitted. We can get around this by binding that expression to a pattern. Since `print_endline` will just return `()`, we can write:

```
let () =
  ...
```

Your use of `{` and `}` is incorrect in this situation, but you can grouped multiple expressions with `;` and `(` and `)`. Remember that `;` is not a "statement terminator" but rather a *separator*.

```
let () =
  if a > b then (
    print_endline "a";
    print_endline "a"
  );
  print_endline "b"
```

*Note that `if` can only exist without a matching `else` if the entire expression returns `unit`. This meets that criteria.*